# Ruby SQL Insert using Mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I'm trying to insert into a remote mysql database. I am able to connect correctly and can query 'select' no problem from it. However, I cannot perform inserts into the same table that I can select from. I suspect it has something to do with my binds, but this is nearly identical to what I was using to get sqlite3 working which I think uses the same Arel to insert.

```
@result = @db.query("insert into lead_to_processes (case_number, style_of_case) values (?,?)", [
      self.case_number.to_blob.force_encoding("UTF-8"),
      self.style_of_case.to_blob.force_encoding("UTF-8")
    ]
)
```

Ultimate goal is to be able query a remote database from inside of a model and insert data into it.  I've tried using Octopus and that didn't quite work because the tables will be different from the databases.

I have full permissions with this user on the database.

So following guidance from comments i changed the syntax and am getting a different error

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

However i'm doing the query like this now

```
@db = Mysql2::Client.new(connectionstring)

 @case_number            =  @db.escape(self.case_number)
 @style_of_case          =  @db.escape(self.style_of_case)

@db.query("insert into lead_to_processes (case_number, style_of_case) VALUES
(#{@case_number}, #{@style_of_case})
```

Any ideas or guidance?  I've also tried this with '' encapsulating the variables that i'm inserting

Comment: Do you get any errors? Could you post them? Do you have write permissions for that database? Or only read?

Comment: I don't believe that the mysql2 gem provides binds for queries, you have to create valid SQL yourself to pass to the query. https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Comment: Can you paste the exception which gets thrown?

Comment: TypeError: can't convert Array into Hash

Comment: you don't need `[]` get rid of them

Comment: Just found another problem with it, still not solved but to_blob puts it in a sqlite3 class, i'm sure that would cause problems inserting to a mysql database    Lead.first.case_number.to_blob.force_encoding("UTF-8").class
SQLite3::Blob

Answer (score 1):

I guess there were some weird characters in my code so I had to force UTF-8 encoding and then removed the characters using gsub below, everything is flowing now.

Thanks for the advice

```
@db.escape(self.style_of_case.force_encoding("UTF-8"))
@db.escape(self.case_number.gsub(/[\xC2]/,'').gsub(/[\xA0]/,'').force_encoding("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are missing an end quote?

this

```
@db.query("insert into lead_to_processes (case_number, style_of_case) VALUES
(#{@case_number}, #{@style_of_case})
```

should be

```
@db.query("insert into lead_to_processes (case_number, style_of_case) VALUES
(#{@case_number}, #{@style_of_case}") <== notice the quote at the end.
```

Comment: thanks for response, posted answer as you were posting this, there were garbage characters in the data that was causing the error.  Thanks for the help though @Karl